# I can't trigger a preview when dropping an image into an input field

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

I have a drop box to upload images to Cloudinary, which works fine, but I can't trigger a preview function when the images are dropped.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="card text-muted">
    <label id="upload" for="dropboxInput" class="card-block text-muted">
       <input type="file" name="file" data-url="CLOUDINARY_URL"
              data-form-data="{CLOUDINARY STUFF}" 
              data-cloudinary-field="file" class="cloudinary-fileupload"
              multiple="multiple" style="display:none" id="dropboxInput">
  </label>                        
</div>
```

This is the code to trigger the function, which works fine when selecting the images after clicking the drop box:

```
var dropboxInput = document.getElementById("dropboxInput");
dropboxInput.onchange = function(){readURL(this)};
```

I have tried this, but it seems that is not getting the dropboxInput.value. The images, once dropped are uploaded:

```
var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox");
dropbox.ondrop = function(){
    readURL(dropboxInput);
};
```

This is the preview function, which handles the preview:

```
function readURL(input){
   if(input.files){

       for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
           var reader = new FileReader();

           reader.onload = function(event) {
                 $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(preview);
           }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
   }    
}
```

In the input field CLOUDINARY STUFF is this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" data-url="https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/MYACCOUNT/auto/upload" 
data-form-data="{&quot;eager&quot;:&quot;c_limit,h_768,w_1024&quot;,&quot;signature&quot;:&quot;1f5c7426f428ebd02bb45180767fd920716cc59e&quot;,&quot;api_key&quot;:&quot;185516472314647&quot;,&quot;eager_async&quot;:true,&quot;callback&quot;:&quot;/cloudinary_cors.html&quot;,&quot;tags&quot;:&quot;Punta de Vistalegre,2&quot;,&quot;use_filename&quot;:true,&quot;timestamp&quot;:&quot;1527959323&quot;}" 
data-cloudinary-field="file" class="cloudinary-fileupload"
multiple="multiple" style="display:none" id="dropboxInput">
```

When the images are droped, I don't find the way to pass them to the readURL() function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the meaning of this construct??? `$($.parseHTML('<img>'))`

Comment: It builds an image for the preview, like this one; <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk....">

Comment: By so does `$(“<img/>”)`

Comment: OK, you are right, that improves the code, but unfortunately  it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was into the **cloudinary-fileupload** function, which has the **drop** option, that handles the dropped files. The input field is generated programmatically with this Java code:

```
 String html = cloudinary.uploader().imageUploadTag("file", options, htmlOptions);
```

And that's the implementation of the drop option:

```
$(".cloudinary-fileupload").cloudinary_fileupload({
   ...
   drop: function(e, data){

         readURL(data);

   },
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing

```
dropbox.ondrop = function(){
  readURL(dropboxInput.value);
};
```

Instead of passing `dropboxIinput.value` try passing only `dropboxInput`
as you're treating the argument as an `input` element.

**Update 1**

I'm not sure I can tell without getting more details. But if by dropping files inside `element#dropbox`, your `input#dropboxInput` is getting changed, you could write your function like this:

```
function readURL(input){
  if(input.files.length){
    for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      image_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[i]);
      $("<img>", {
        src: image_url
      }).appendTo(preview);
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: You may be pointing the right direction. Setting a log to count the files collected into the readURL(), with my initial setting I get **NaN**, but passing readURL(dropboxInput) I get 0. When all the dropped images are uploaded correctly. I wonder why the **change** event is not enough, when dropping, as it is when clicking.

Comment: Kumar, I've tested your function, which gives a cleaner value for the image as an URL. But my problem is that this function, which handles the preview, doesn't receive the image files when they are dropped into the input field. I've added the code represented as CLOUDINARY STUFF, just in case it could help.